# Generating linq Query

Tags: sql, linq, oracle, linq-to-sql

I am using Microsoft PUBS database in this there is two relational table publisher and pub_info publisher have primary key on pub_id field and pub_info have foreign key of publisher table pub_id

i am trying to get those record which is available in publisher table but not in pub_info table using linq query
 i know the query in sql

```
select pub_id from publisher where pub_id not in(select pub_id from pub_info);

var data =db.publisher.where(x=>db.pub_info.select(x1=>x1.pub_id).Contains(x)).Select(x.pub_id)
```

getting Error while executing this query

but i am not able to get idea about to generate the same query in linq

Comment: Asking a question [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016597/generating-linq-query) is very bad!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something like that

```
var excludedIds = db.pub_info.Select(pi => pi.pub_id).ToArray();

var data = db.publisher.Where(p => !excludedIds.Contains(p.pub_id);
```

I might be wrong, but I think I remember that it can't be made in one round.

EDIT : not made in one round means that I think you have to "enumerate" the excludedIds.
But you can write that in one query, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this:

```
var data=(from p in db.publisher
          where !(from pi in db.pub_info
                  select pi.pub_id
                  ).Contains(p.pub_id)
          select p.pub_id
         );
```

Or this might also work:

```
var data=(from p in db.publisher
          where !db.pub_info.Select(pi => pi.pub_id).Contains(p.pub_id)
          select p.pub_id
         );
```